# Will the Compiz version's dash be the same as the current dash?

Tags: unity, 11.04

Since the Compiz version of Unity does not have a dash at the moment, I was wondering if the Unity team is planning to port the current version of the dash "as it is" (eight huge icons to open Firefox / categorized apps / Software Center), as seen here...

[image]

...or will rather introduce some changes here and there, and in this case, how extensive the planned changes are going to be, e.g. somehow merging the apps, places and people menus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 11.04, you'll be able to remove the home screen shortcuts, and of course add them back.

Comment: Will you also be able to set custom ones?

Comment: I hope so. . . .

Answer (score 5):

I don't think anything like that has been decided as of yet.

*The best way to predict the future is [to invent it](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu?searchtext=unity).* :-)